# AES Android Encryption C# decryption Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: c#, android, .net, wcf, encryption

I have a problem related to AES decryption on my server side.
When encrypting data in the android client and sending it to the WCF server, the server always return an exception like

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is
>   invalid and cannot be removed.    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.DepadBlock(Byte[]
>   block, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[]
>   inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()    at
>   WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Decrypt(Byte[] p_EncryptedMsg, Byte[]
>   p_key, Byte[] p_iv) in c:\users\omr\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line
>   76    at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\users\omr\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line
>   94}

my android encryption is

```
public static String enc(String message) {

    byte[] keyInBytes = KEY.getBytes();
    byte[] encryptedData = null;
    KeyGenerator kgen;
    try {
        kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        secureRandom.setSeed(keyInBytes);

        kgen.init(256, secureRandom);

        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

        key = skey.getEncoded();

        try {
            encryptedData = encrypt(key, message.getBytes());
            Log.w("ENC ", new String(encryptedData));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);

    // return message;
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] testMessage)
        throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, /* "PBEWithSHA1And128BitAES-CBC-BC" */
    "AES");
    final byte[] iv = KEY.getBytes();

    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(testMessage);
    try {
        decrypt(raw, encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

and my C# code is

```
public String Decrypt(byte[] p_EncryptedMsg, byte[] p_key, byte[] p_iv)
    {

         m_key = new byte[32];
        m_iv = new byte[16];
        Array.Clear(m_key, 0, 32);
        Array.Clear(m_iv, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(p_key, m_key, p_key.Length > 32 ? 32 : p_key.Length);
        Array.Copy(p_iv, m_iv, p_iv.Length > 16 ? 16 : p_iv.Length);


        if (m_key == null || m_iv == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key or IV is equal to null");

        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {

            aesProvider.Key = m_key;
            aesProvider.IV = m_iv;
            aesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                CryptoStream decStream = new CryptoStream(memStream,                aesProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                decStream.Write(p_EncryptedMsg, 0, p_EncryptedMsg.Length);
                decStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                String res = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE:
I can encrypt and decrypt the text again correctly in the android side.

Comment: How are you passing the IV and Key to the .NET code?

Comment: IV is the same value as the raw key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that the problem happened as a result of using         SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

as the server side take only the keyInBytes from me not the randomized one, so he can't generate the correct decryption key.

C# code example

```
using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCryptoServiceProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aesCryptoServiceProvider.Key = key;
                aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV = iv;
                aesCryptoServiceProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aesCryptoServiceProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    cryptoStream.Write(p_EncryptedMsg, 0, encryptedMsg.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Omar, I have same issue. How did u convert keyinbytes in c#? I have same implementation like yours. I have andriod encrypted file but I want to decrypt it in c#.

Comment: I can share my andriod java file if required.

Comment: I have one xml file which is encrypted. What I am doing is I retrive the byte array of that file and store it in `byte array`. I convert the key by using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and vector i.e. `iv` `byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };` and I pass this to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one problem I see is that your CipherMode on the .Net side should be ECB to match the Java side. Give that a shot and see if that works.

Comment: the two sides uses CBC as encryption mode and PKCS7Padding for padding